# Book about government department controlling the release of advanced technology

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, artificial-gravity

I read a book a few months/years/lifetimes ago. To be fairly specific about it, without giving away the plot, it's about a scientist and his team that discover how to create and control gravity and change it's orientation. On the night of the discovery, their deaths are faked and they are all kidnapped by a government department that has been controlling the release of advanced technology to the general public for the past 50ish years. They have access to working fusion, cancer cures, advanced AI etc etc.

They give the scientists the choice of joining them or being put in a 'prison' like thing, where they'll stay for x amount of years before being given the choice of joining again. Main character escapes prison and goes on vendetta style thing.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're wanting people to help you identify your book then **please don't intentionally hold back info about the novel**. If you think it's spoilerish, use spoiler tags >!

Comment: Normal people don't mind spoilers--we're talking about fiction here, not crossword puzzles--and spoilerphobes woule be well advised to avoid story-identification questions, which are inherently spoilerish.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122864/imprisoned-in-rock (which is newer but has an OP-provided answer)

Answer (score 4):

The book is *[Influx](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0525953183)*, by Daniel Suarez:

> Particle physicist Jon Grady is ecstatic when his team achieves what they’ve been working toward for years: a device that can reflect gravity. Their research will revolutionize the field of physics—the crowning achievement of a career. Grady expects widespread acclaim for his entire team. The Nobel Prize. Instead, his lab is locked down by a shadowy organization whose mission is to prevent at all costs the social upheaval sudden technological advances bring. This Bureau of Technology Control uses the advanced technologies they have harvested over the decades...