# Imprisoned in Rock

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book where one of the character woke to find they were imprisoned, inside a room in a rock, with only a computer arm, controlled by a computer mind, to monitor / punish them. The character (think it was a male) managed to communicate with others, who had subverted the computers controlling their environment.

They were placed inside the rock by a machine that burrowed down through the rock, but which the characters could not then escape through. The characters eventually escape and the imprisonment is only a small part of the story.

I think they were imprisoned because they refuse to join another characters organisation.

Does anyone recognise this story and remember the book title?

Comment: When did you read it? How old is the book? Who was it aimed at? What nationality/language was it?

Comment: It was in the last 10 years and it was a new book then. English and technology focused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the book, it is *[Influx](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22668803-influx)* by Daniel Suarez.

[image]

When the inventor of anti-gravity refuses to join the Bureau of Technology Control, he is imprisoned with other geniuses, until they escape and fight back.

Answer (score 1):

This has some similarities with [I Have No Mouth, and I Must Scream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_No_Mouth,_and_I_Must_Scream) by Harlan Ellison, except for the part about someone else taking control of the computer. In this story, the computer was entirely in control.

Comment: Thank you, but no, that's not it. I think the character was sent there as a punishment, as were a lot of other people who were classed as 'against the system'.